# Detect on disconnect user signalr

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, websocket, signalr

I need to detect when users connect and disconnect using signalr.

I have these 2 hub methods:

```
public void Say(string message)
{
    Trace.WriteLine(message + " - " + Context.ConnectionId);
}

public void Goodbye(string message)
{
    Trace.WriteLine(message + " - " + Context.ConnectionId);
}
```

I have implemented the `Say` method which takes care of detecting a connection like so:

```
$.connection.hub
            .start()
            .done(function () {
                hub.server.say("Hello SignalR");
});
```

But how do I detect disconnect?

Comment: `$.connection.hub.disconnected(function () { …` on the client and/or overriding `OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled) {` in the hub.

Comment: @stuartd I don't seem to be able to call hub methods in the callback, $.connection.hub.disconnected(function () {
                hub.server.goodbye("bye");
            }); does not work

Comment: Well it woudn't work, as **the client is disconnected**

Comment: Indeed you don't need to call any method explicitly from client (as it's already disconnected in that moment). OnDisconnected on server side is called by SignalR framework by default.

Comment: Even better, thanks guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this overriden method into your `Hub` class:

```
public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
{
    // do the logging here
    Trace.WriteLine(Context.ConnectionId + ' - disconnected');
    return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
}
```

This will handle and log disconects on server side while I think it doesn't make much sense to track it on `client` side as it's unlikely your SignalR session would be terminated from server side - [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15889367/disconnect-client-from-server-side-signalr).

Edit in regard to `@stuartd` comment:
you could also override

```
public override Task OnReconnected()
{
    Trace.WriteLine(Context.ConnectionId + ' - reconnected');
    return base.OnReconnected();
}
```

so you'll be able to track cases when Client tried reconnect to Server and succeed.

Edit#2:
Then you can of course use same mechanism for tracking of `OnConnected` event

```
public override Task OnConnected()
{
    Trace.WriteLine(Context.ConnectionId + ' - reconnected');
    return base.OnConnected();
}
```

So all tracking code is conveniently kept just on server-side which is more robust in cases when client is logged into hub but for some reason failed to execute method you're using to track logged state.

Comment: Indeed but I don't think it makes difference. When this method is called serverside already considers client as disconnected, in case it will succeed in reconnecting from client side it should call `public override Task OnReconnected()` of `Hub` class so it could be logged as well anyway or am I missing something?

Comment: Good resource is this page:https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server 'How to handle connection lifetime events in the Hub class' and it's sub sections.

Comment: In `AspNetCore.SignalR` I needed `public override Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception? e)`.

Answer (score 2):

In AspNetCore.SignalR

```
public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception? exception)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine(Context.ConnectionId + ' - disconnected');
            await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
        }
```